# Kendo and angular conflict in routing

Tags: kendo-ui, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

My spa mobile application works correctly with angular route but makes multiple request per hash change for load template on for angular route for html file and another for kendo route! How can I disable kendo routing and only use angular route?

I use this angular route

```
  routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "./views/home.html",
            controller: "HomeController",
        })
        .when("/details/:itemId", {
            templateUrl: "./views/details.html",
            controller: "DetailsController",
        })
        .when("/menu", {
            templateUrl: "./views/menu.html",
            controller: "MenuController",
        })
        .when("/cart", {
            templateUrl: "./views/cart.html",
            controller: "CartController",
        })
        .when("/account", {
            templateUrl: "./views/account.html"
            ,controller: "AccountController"
        })
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "./views/about.html",
            controller: "AboutController",

        })
        .when("/done", {
            templateUrl: "./views/done.html",
            controller: "DoneController",
        })
    ;
```